# execute command at entities around an arrow

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

as stated in the title I want to make a arrow that executes a command on all entities in a certain range of the arrow, the range I would like to be 10x10 from the center of the arrow. but I have not been able to get it working.

```
execute as @e[type=spectral_arrow,tag=ShotFromLightningBow] at @s run execute as @e[tag=!MageAlly,distance=10..10] run effect give @s wither 5 5 true
```

This is what I tried last.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the distance tag. `distance=a..b` means the distance to the entity must be between the numbers a and b (both inclusive). In your command both are 10, meaning the effect only gets applied to entities with a distance of exactly 10 blocks. You proboably want to do `distance=..a`, which means all entities that are at most a blocks away.

Comment: so if i understand it right, the distance=a..b is used like a circle where A means the distance from the player to the starting detection area, and B is the end of the detection area?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. The distance `a..b` is the inner and outer radius of a spherical detection. So `3..5` would detect anything that is a minimum of 3 but a maximum of 5 blocks away.